# Sending Byte array to Galaxy Gear Live from the mobile

Tags: android, wear-os, serial-communication, android-wear-data-api, samsung-galaxy-gear

I have been developing an app to read serial data from the micro usb  port of the Samsung S4 using OTG cable. Now I want to send these data to the Android wear app runs on Galaxy Gear Live. 
The problem I face is that, I know we can send Strings to the android wear app using the message API, but how can I send a byte array to the gear app?

Any pointers are welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `DataMap` object. It is similar to `Bundle`, but is sent between the mobile and the wearable. So first you put a byte array into a the `DataMap` using [DataMap.putByteArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/DataMap.html#putByteArray(java.lang.String,%20byte[])) and then serialize it to byte array itself by calling [DataMap.toByteArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/DataMap.html#toByteArray()). Then you just send it using [MessageApi.sendMessage](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html).

You might notice, that `MessageApi.sendMessage` already accepts a byte array, so you could put your data directly there. However, you probably will want to add some metadata to your call. Even if not now, then in the future. It's best to future-proof your code and use the serialized `DataMap`.

Comment: Hi Gruszczy, Than you for the answer. I will try that method and let you know.

Comment: Hi, I am facing some issues trying to convert the received byte array. Can you explain what you meant by "adding metadata to your call" ?

Comment: I'm glad :) Happy hacking on Android Wear.